# C# Convert IEnumerable to IList using .ToList()?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ilist

I am using an external library thats returns a `IEnumerable`. After I have recieved them I would like to add some models to the end. That only seems possible when using an `IList` or some other collection. So when i'm trying to convert the `IEnumerable` to a list using the `.ToList()` method it returns an `IEnumerable`. That's not the what I expected? Am I using `.ToList()` correct? Or what else would solve my problem?

This is my code i have so far:

```
IList<Models.Browser.Language> languages = GetLanguages(dateDrom, dateTo).ToList();
IList<Models.Browser.Language> primaryItems = languages.Take(10);
```

This last line produces an error saying:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Bogus.Models.Browser.Language>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Bogus.Models.Browser.Language>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The value of `languages` is a reference to a `List<>`, but then you're calling `Take(10)` on that, which *doesn't* return a list.

Just move your `ToList()` call:

```
IEnumerable<Models.Browser.Language> languages = GetLanguages(dateDrom, dateTo);
IList<Models.Browser.Language> primaryItems = languages.Take(10).ToList();
```

Or just do it in one call:

```
var primaryItems = GetLanguages(dateDrom, dateTo).Take(10).ToList();
```

Also, this isn't quite correct:

> After I have recieved them I would like to add some models to the end.

An alternative is to use `Concat`. For example:

```
var items = GetLanguages(dateDrom, dateTo).Take(10).Concat(fixedItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for the insanely fast aswer. It now works as expected. Really appreciate your help!